# Defining y-axis range and breaks in package sjPlot:: plot_model()

Tags: r

I am plotting the results of my GlmmTMB model with the sjplot package and the function plot_model (max.m3) in R. Here is the Code:

```
p=sjPlot::plot_model(max.m3, type="pred", grid = F)
```

These are six graphics which are plotted than. However, I would like to define y-axis range (ranging from 0 to 10) and shown breaks (0,5,10 = so that tick marks appear at 0, 5, and 10).

Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you plot marginal effects for all model terms, `plot_model()` returns a *list* of ggplot-objects. You can then modify each plot in the list, simply using ggplot-commands.

```r
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + gear + cyl + drat, data = mtcars)
p <- sjPlot::plot_model(m, type = "pred", grid = FALSE)
p[[1]] + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(15, 30), breaks = c(15, 25, 30))
p[[2]] + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5, 40), breaks = c(15, 25, 40))
...
```

If you want to apply the same y-limits and breaks to all plots, you can loop over the list, e.g.:

```r
library(ggplot2)
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + gear + cyl + drat, data = mtcars)
p <- sjPlot::plot_model(m, type = "pred", grid = FALSE)
lapply(p, function(i) i + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(15, 30), breaks = c(15, 25, 30)))
```